# Calling an api and return these values in Nodejs

Tags: api, express, axios

I am trying to build a small website. In that i using React for frontend, Nodejs for backend, and some third party api. Here my idea is, first to post the form data to nodejs. And from then i accepting that data in node and need to call an external api. For this purpose i am using axios. After receiving values from my api i have to send that value back to react application. And when i run my code in postman, the output is {}. I think that i am not getting values from  my api but dont know how to resolve this. And i am new to these technologies. Someone pls help me to sort out this problem. Thanking you in advance. Here is my what i have tried so far.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false}));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(" Express Homepage is running...");
});

async function callApi(emailid, pswd) {
    return axios({
        method:'post',
        url:'http://51.X.X/api/login',
        data:  { 
            "email": `${emailid}`,
            "password": `${pswd}`
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })};
    callApi().then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
   let emailid = String(req.body.email);
   let pswd = String(req.body.password);
  const data = callApi(emailid, pswd);
   if(data) {
    res.send(data);
   }else {
       res.json({msg : " Response data not recieved.."})
   }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use async/await syntax to handle asynchronous calls

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
   let emailid = String(req.body.email);
   let pswd = String(req.body.password);
  const data = await callApi(emailid, pswd);
   if(data) {
    res.send(data);
   }else {
       res.json({msg : " Response data not recieved.."})
   }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not waiting for async call to finish.
use async-await as mentioned in official doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

```
function callAPI(){
    const response = await axios({
       method:'post',
       url:'http://51.X.X/api/login',
       data:  { 
          "email": `${emailid}`,
          "password": `${pswd}`
       },
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })};

    return response
}

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
   let emailid = String(req.body.email);
   let pswd = String(req.body.password);
   //add try catch to catch exception
   const data = await callApi(emailid, pswd);
   if(data) {
       //check for response from axios in official doc and send what data you
       want to send
       res.send(data);
   }else {
      res.json({msg : " Response data not recieved.."})
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, alot axios post request does return the value, but i am not getting the values in "const data"  to use it further. My response is a js object. how to do this..

Comment: Axios must return the response, can you show me how did you implemented it.